# React Native: How to deteck iPhones with Notch?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to make a specific case for `iPhone Xs Max` in `react native`?

That is the bit of code I have for `IphoneX` from [react-native-iphone-x-helper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-iphone-x-helper)

```
export function isIphoneX() {
    let dimen = Dimensions.get('window');
    return (
        Platform.OS === 'ios' &&
        !Platform.isPad &&
        !Platform.isTVOS &&
        (dimen.height === 812 || dimen.width === 812)
    );
}
```

What are the dimensions of `iPhone Xs Max` and would that be enough just to add the `iPhone Xs Max` dimensions?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In the end I went with this:

```js
    export function isIphoneXorAbove() {
      const dimen = Dimensions.get('window');
      return (
        Platform.OS === 'ios' &&
        !Platform.isPad &&
        !Platform.isTVOS &&
        ((dimen.height === 812 || dimen.width === 812) || (dimen.height === 896 || dimen.width === 896))
      );
    }
```

But all the credit goes to this [PR](https://github.com/ptelad/react-native-iphone-x-helper/pull/9)

**EDIT:**
If you want this function to work with iPhone 11 and iPhone 12 variations you can use this function instead:

```js
function isIphoneWithNotch() {
  const dimen = Dimensions.get('window');
  return (
    Platform.OS === 'ios' &&
    !Platform.isPad &&
    !Platform.isTV &&
    (dimen.height === 780 ||
      dimen.width === 780 ||
      dimen.height === 812 ||
      dimen.width === 812 ||
      dimen.height === 844 ||
      dimen.width === 844 ||
      dimen.height === 896 ||
      dimen.width === 896 ||
      dimen.height === 926 ||
      dimen.width === 926)
  );
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
In the end, I went with a cleaner approach using [react-native-device-info](https://github.com/react-native-device-info/react-native-device-info)

```js
const deviceId = DeviceInfo.getDeviceId();
const iphonesWithNotch = [
  'iPhone10,3',
  'iPhone11,2',
  'iPhone11,4',
  'iPhone11,6',
  'iPhone11,8',
  'iPhone12,1',
  'iPhone12,3',
  'iPhone12,5',
  'iPhone12,8',
  'iPhone13,1',
  'iPhone13,2',
  'iPhone13,3',
  'iPhone13,4',
  'iPhone14,2',
  'iPhone14,3',
  'iPhone14,4',
  'iPhone14,5',
  'iPhone14,6',
  'iPhone14,7',
  'iPhone14,8',
];

const isIphoneWithNotch = iphonesWithNotch.includes(deviceId);
```

Or even simpler:

```js
let hasNotch = DeviceInfo.hasNotch();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `https://github.com/ptelad/react-native-iphone-x-helper` package. It allows you to design your react-native app for the `iPhone X, XS, XS Max & XR`

Comment: what about iphone 11 and 12